# What to do if a laptop ONLY has "superspeed" USB 3.0 ports?

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

I bought a [Dell Inspiron 15 7000 gaming laptop](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/inspiron-15-7000-gaming/spd/inspiron-15-7567-laptop/) and it *only* has USB 3.0 "SuperSpeed" ports. There isn't a single USB 2.0 port. With these ports, my keyboard  and mouse simply do not fit into any of the ports.

I looked around forums for mice/keyboard that would fit these ports, but the only answer I found was that nobody makes them, because there's no need for a super fast mouse.

These are the ports:
[image]

1. Combo Jack (Headset/Mic)
2. USB 3.0 port
3. USB 3.0 Powershare port
4. HDMI
5. Gigabit Ethernet
6. Noble Lock Security Slot |
7. Power
8. USB 3.0 port
9. Media Card Reader

So how do I connect my mouse and keyboard? Is the only option to get some kind of 3.0 -> 2.0 converter?

**Update**: I just got off the phone with Dell support.  They suggested I find a Bluetooth mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Yes, or go wireless. USB C to 2.0 adapters are ~US$8 for a pair at Amazon or elsewhere. https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-iXCC-Female-Converter-OnePlus/dp/B0727PB8G7/ref=sr_1_11

Comment: And any keyboard/mouse work perfectly in USB3.0 ports. The USB version isn't related to the form factor. Hard to believe your laptop hasn't at least one standard USB3.0 port. Can you please [edit] and post the hardware specs or brand/model of that odd laptop?

Comment: USB "superspeed" ports are normally the same as old ports just with additional pins. Do you mean USB [Type C ports as opposed to Type A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqcRQ.jpg)?

Comment: No, these are not USB C ports.  It actually looks very similar to a 2.0 port, but none of my 2.0 devices fit in them.  The "superspeed" logo is next to them: a little SS next to the USB symbol.

Comment: This laptop has standard USB A type ports, there should be no issue with your mouse and keyboard connecting to them. USB A is the same for all USB revisions (1.0 through 3.1), if they don't "fit" then they are not standard which I would find odd. It is possible that they may fit very tight, given the laptop is new there is likely no wear whatsoever on the ports yet, although they shouldn't be too tight.

Comment: @David Try flipping your connector the other way up. USB 3.0 Type-A connectors are fully backward compatible with earlier Type-A connectors.

Comment: @spiff That didn't work - that would have been just too easy!

Comment: @David try one of the other USB ports. I see from the Dell link you posted that one of the USB ports are "PowerShare", maybe that is preventing you from plugging it in. As others have said above, USB 3.0 connectors are backwards compatible and you should have no trouble using a USB 2.0 device.

Comment: Your mouse must have a non-standard USB connector, or it is not a USB mouse. We can all see with our own eyes that the laptop (if it is the same you linked to) that it has two USB-A connectiors on the right side, and one on the left side.

Comment: I too have sometimes problems to get a USB device in. For example, at work I work with very new HP ProBook's and I tried to insert a USB stick and at first it seemed impossible, but after some more trying I did get it in.

Comment: USB 3.0 is backwards compatible with USB 2.  So 3.0 to 2.0 converter doesn’t exist for obvious reasons

Comment: Can you modify anything in the BIOS to change USB port emulation or download updated USB drivers? This sounds like a driver/firmware issue.

Comment: Look inside the USB ports with a penlight and see if there's any packing material stuck inside.  The ports are type A connectors, and Dell even sells an optional external USB 2.0 optical drive that uses the port.  Any type A plug should fit if oriented right side up.  If no USB 2.0 device will fit in any of the USB ports, there's something else going on, in which case there isn't enough information here to diagnose the issue.

Comment: David, your update about the advice from Dell doesn't mean that you should not be able to use those ports.  It sounds like they just suggested a workaround so as not to have to figure out what your problem is.

Comment: I don't understand why this is still going on... I just pulled my Latitude 5580 out which has ONLY USB 3.0 ports as well, 3 USB type-A and 1 USB type-C, and Cougar gaming keyboard and mouse both work just fine, and they are USB 2.0 devices. Are you staying you can't physically plug them in, or are they just not seen?

Comment: Alright, well I finally figured it out.  The solution was just to "push really hard."  So hard, in fact, I was afraid it was going to break.  Sounds similar to what @LPChip was dealing with.  Anyway, thanks to everyone who tried to figure this out with me.  I guess super tight connections is just something I should expect from a brand new computer.

Comment: I don't see any point in downvoting this question. This may appear obvious for many of us, but the OP really had an issue, tried to solve it by himself and also explained what has been tried. Downvoting on this is just elitist stupidity. Anyway, glad the OP found the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a photo of three Dell 'Super Speed' USB 3 ports.

One port has a USB 2 Logitech dongle, one is free, and one has a USB 3 hard disk plugged in. All USB 2 devices will fit. Try the other way up, and wiggle it a bit.

[image]